# How to display a sidebar only for blog?

Tags: sidebar

I have 2 sidebars(primary and secondary). I want the secondary sidebar to display only on the blog page and primary sidebar to display everywhere else except for the blog page.
What have I tried:

In functions.php :

```
if (is_page('blog-35')) {
    get_sidebar('secondary');
} else {
    get_sidebar('primary');
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any hints on how to debug this? I don't understand what am I doing wrong in the code above.(blog-35 is the body class of the page I want to display only the secondary sidebar)

Answer (score 0):

First: [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) expects a page id, so the call would be `is_page(35)`.

Second: [`get_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) needs to be called from the template (not the functions file).

You probably already have two templates setup:

- `page.php` - In here you'll call `get_sidebar('primary');`
- `index.php` (assuming your blog is on the home page) - In here you'll call `get_sidebar('secondary');`

Please let me know if this answers your questions!

Comment: `is_page()` works fine with slugs: `@param mixed $page Page ID, title, slug, or array of such.`

Comment: I was unaware of the slug usage with is_page ... turns out you can also use page title. That's why I love Stack Exchange, forever learning something new

Comment: did moving your calls from functions.php to the appropriate template file solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing I did on the athemeart blog page and below is the code

```
if( is_home() && is_active_sidebar( 'athemeart-sidebar' )  ):
  dynamic_sidebar( 'athemeart-sidebar' );
endif;
```

Thanks